# How do I assign this modified array to a variable?

Tags: groovy

Try to do this as a one-liner, a little confused why this doesn't work:

```
var= balh.getArrayOStrings('sdfsfd').each{ it.replaceAll("herp","derp") }
```

I call a method that returns an array of string. I loop over them and do a replace and assign back to var, but the modified strings in the array are not assigned back to var. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` returns the original list, try

```
balh = [:]
balh.getArrayOStrings = { x ->
    [ "sudhpa Herp", "pskaap herp", "herp lsjkda"]
}

var = balh.getArrayOStrings('sdfsfd').collect { it.replaceAll("herp","derp") }
```

=> `[sudhpa Herp, pskaap derp, derp lsjkda]`

Comment: Or just `balh.getArrayOStrings('sdfsfd')*.replaceAll("herp","derp")` for short by using the spread operator.